# HTML Forms Textbox Dynamic Information Boxes?

Tags: html, css, forms, dynamic, popup

I have done several recent Google searches about what I'm looking for, but I don't know the proper name for what I am looking for which makes it nearly impossible to get results. Let me try and explain it:

I've seen on websites on form registrations where when the user clicks on the "email" field, a popup information box will appear next to it saying something along the lines of "Please enter a valid email..." and if the user moves onto the next box and the email ISN'T valid, the box turns red and it says something like "Please enter a VALID email." If the email is already taken, the box turns red and says that it's taken and they need to enter a different one. If it meets all requirements, the box disappears and the next box will pop up asking for a username, checks if the username is unique, etc etc for other fields. Finally, when it comes time for the password, it dynamically checks if the passwords match and if they don't, the info box turns red again.

Does anyone understand what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the term you're asking for is `form validation`.
There are countless examples online relating to this, and they are many different ways in which forms are validated.
For the `email` fields that you mentioned above, you'll want to use the `required` attribute (Thanks to HTML5, this is really easy), in which the browser can be used to validate (in a limited fashion) the email address.

**Basic Example**:

```
Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
```

**Made-From Scratch Visual Reference**

You can accomplish with basic `HTML` and `CSS`. Here is a **JSFiddle** I made: http://jsfiddle.net/aZ9r8/331/

**Javascript Library**

Here is a popular Javascript libary at http://www.parsleyjs.org.

Comment: This is one way to solve my problem, but I was hoping for a more visual approach. If I can find an example of a service that provides what I am looking for, I'll link it.

Comment: What do you mean by a "visual" approach? Do you mean showing displays indicating whether the input is valid or not?

Comment: Yes! I'm looking for little colored information boxes to appear to the right of the form fields as focus is gained on them.

Comment: @Configure - I finished the visual reference. Please check my answer if you accept it so that others can view it.

Comment: You understand the concept of my question, but I'm looking for perhaps a library of a built-in professional box that animates on/off, has color properties and is dynamic. If you could point me in the right direction to such a library or service; that's what I'm searching for.

Comment: parsleyjs.org is a popular JavaScript form validation library.